# Sharing page URL on LinkedIn

Tags: angular, typescript, linkedin-api

I develop web application in Angular 4 and I need to sharing page URL on LinkedIn profile. After insertions of Login data I've got a following message: https://prnt.sc/z7fd5o.
I had implemented sharing with Facebook and it's work but I don't know why I cant sharing URL on LinkedIn.
Here is my code for function for sharing:

```
private linkedinShare():void{
    let winOpts : WindowParamsInterface = this.getShareWindowParams();
    window.open(this.linkedinShareLink + 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(this.permalinkUrl),
    null, //name 
    'top=' + winOpts.top + ',left=' + winOpts.left + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width=' + winOpts.width + ',height=' + winOpts.height
  );
  }
```

where this.linkedinShareLink has value https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/? and this.permalinkUrl has a value https://igeo.igea.hr/?themeId=2149113&bbox=21910.00000000006,4747510,958090,5112490&v_layers=__igeo_layer_1%2Cbase_overlay_NUTS%2C__lti_3332292%2CsketchesLayer%2CwebsocketDrawLayer%2CmeasurementsLayer. The same problem was with sharing a Google maps URL. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `?` in the `linkedinShareLink`, the correct value should be this one: `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=`

Furthermore, I suggest you to encode the url using something like `fixedEncodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURIComponent`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript/61843371#61843371) for more detailed informations.